# Crear un botón para recorrer fila por fila una hoja y mostrarla en otra en excel usando macros

Tags: excel, vba, macros, excel-2013, excel-2010

Deseo crear un formulario para poder recorrer fila por fila una hoja en Excel y mostrar los valores en otra.

Esta es la hoja donde quiero mostrar los datos usando el botón "siguiente". Cada vez que haga clic deseo que recorra los datos de la Hoja 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la Hoja 2, de donde voy a obtener los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilicé este código pensando en que funcionaria, pero siempre se queda en el segunda fila (Mónica Rojas Varilla 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)

```
Sub siguiente()
Dim fila As Integer
Sheets("Hoja 2").Select
Cells(3, 2).Select
fila = ActiveCell.Row
If fila > 3 Or fila = 3 Then
fila = fila + 1
Range(Cells(fila, 2), Cells(fila, 11)).Copy
Sheets("Hoja 1").Select
Range("B9:k9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

End Sub
```

Gracias por sus respuestas!!!

Answer (score 2):

Cada vez que ejecutas tu código, siempre le haces volver a la celda (3,2), es decir, B3. Por lo tanto, siempre va a mostrarte a Mónica.

Llévate la variable fila fuera del procedimiento y que sea global en el módulo, de tal forma que cada vez que la ejecutes, recuerde el valor de la última ejecución (hasta que cierres Excel).

Para declararla global, simplemente borra la línea `Dim Fila as Integer` y arriba del todo pon `Dim Fila as Integer` Y modifica tu código un poco, porque puedes simplificarlo.

Algo así debería servirte.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Fila As Integer

Sub siguiente()

Fila = Fila + 1
If Fila < 3 Then Fila = 3
Sheets("Hoja 2").Range(Cells(Fila, 2), Cells(Fila, 11)).Copy
Sheets("Hoja 1").Range("B9:k9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Ejemplo en vídeo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Elier Sánchez, te agradezco por la respuesta pero ya probé de esa forma, el inconveniente es que por defecto el valor de la variable Fila es 1, y se queda en la segunda fila(Fila = Fila + 1, Fila = 1+1).

Comment: Si lo ejecutas varias veces seguidas, al ejecutarlo la segunda vez, el valor pasa a ser 4, 5, 6, y así. De hecho, mira la respuesta actualizada, y verás que cada vez que hago clic en Siguiente, el valor se Fila se incrementa. Algo no has puesto en su sitio.